# Drupal 8:The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Drupal 8:The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later. i am getting this error while installing the drupal 8

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIBeh.png)

I have already installed the XAMPP.

Comment: As as side comment, if possible, think about using Drupal 10.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer your question but first step is to find out why it casts an error. By default Drupal isn't very verbose in such a case.

Add following at the end of your settings.php file and you will see more output and hopefully something obvious to track

```
$config['system.logging']['error_level']='verbose';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic message that drupal floats when things don't go right. You can also use the following steps to find the actual issue :

1. Add dblog module if not already present on the site and drush setup.
2. Now enable this module using drush `drush en dblog`
3. Now just execute `drush ws` , this will show you the complete error message on console that your site is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is newly installed Drupal, maybe there is some issues on `settings.php`. wrong database credentials, or database not present etc. Check it.

Drupal will install no matter what. Can you add more details to it. Or, can you open xampp logs, and find for clues.